# checkbox validation in my form

Tags: jquery

I dont' know why this is not working even alert function is not working.can any one figure out what is the error here.
Here is my javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.subject').each(function() { 
alert('ok');
if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) { 
alert('not selected!'); 
} 
else{ 
alert('selected!'); 
} 
}); 
</script>

<form  name="f1">
<tr>
<td>
<p style="color:#999; font-size:14px; text-align:right; margin:0px;">Please select Your Medium :</p>
</td>
<td class="subject">
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="hindi">Hindi
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="english">English
<input type="checkbox" name="subject[]"  value="regional">Regional Language
</td>
</tr><!--end of select medium-->
<input type="submit" name="land" class="butt" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The DOM is not ready.

Comment: what engine I have download

Comment: What Karl-AndréGagnon is saying is that you're executing your jQuery code before the elements have been created. You need to either move your code to the end of the page, or better yet wrap them in a document.ready call (see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: And the obvious next issue to me is that your jQuery is searching for elements with the class `subject`, however I see none.

Comment: what shall I write in class subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your existing code in a document.ready wrapper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(){
    $('.subject').each(function() { 
        alert('ok');
        if($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) { 
            alert('not selected!'); 
        }else{ 
            alert('selected!'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Computers are fast -- so fast that your code will execute as soon as it's downloaded. If it downloads before the DOM has been fully constructed, it may try to access elements that have not yet been built -- and fail.

Solution: the document.ready wrapper, which tells the code to wait until the DOM has been constructed before running. A common error, and one I've made dozens of times myself.

---

Here's a simple example of code validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/W4g4e/7/

First, create an assoc array with `fieldName` : `fieldID` pairs.

Then, loop through all field IDs and check if valid. If not, display an error message (1) using the human-friendly field name, and (2) `focus()` on the fieldID.

Comment: I have implemented not validating

Comment: Note that `$(function () { //code });` is a short form of `$(document).ready({ //code });`

Comment: Thanks for your timing and your knowledge sharing .can you do that for my form I have implemented my code. still it is not coming.

Comment: my dear friend  just like you he helped me. I don't see any variation on both of them.for me both answer is well.since I am individual person working on all project.I am doing marketing, hosting,coding and requirement,only help for me is stackteam.always I need you help. since your js fiddle is hard to understand me that it.if you give solution for my form it is great .

Comment: If both answers were helpful, then you should upvote both answers (the ^ triangle beside the answer. Choosing a correct answer is entirely your choice - neither of us will mind.

Comment: The best way to solve your problem is to break it into parts. **Each part should be a different S.O. question.** It might sound like a lot of work, but you will save *hours* getting your answers. Also, more people will be involved in solving each part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to run this when the document loads?

[heres an example where its run when you click the submit button](http://jsfiddle.net/5x7q5fyj/1/)

```
$('.butt').on('click', function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (k, val) {
        if ($(val).is(':checked')) {
            console.log('this is checked:', val);
        } else {
            console.log('this is not checked:', val);
        }
    });
});
```

if you want it to run when the document is ready, it's like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (k, val) {
        if ($(val).is(':checked')) {
            console.log('this is checked:', val);
        } else {
            console.log('this is not checked:', val);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using console.log instead of alert, but you can just replace console.log with alert.

---

If you wan't it to use alert then use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5x7q5fyj/4/):

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (k, val) {
        if ($(val).is(':checked')) {
            alert('this is checked:');
        } else {
            alert('this is not checked:');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks alert is not coming boss

Comment: once again thanks lot where to put ! I want to show when any one checkbox is null I don't want to check with checked. is this correct if(!$(val).is(':checked:');  more over if click finally submit button the action should happen

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you are trying to say. The `if ($(val).is(':checked'))` checkes if the checkbox is checks, and then it will perform what ever is in the if statement..